# IP Addresses showing up unusual in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a star rating system I am trying to get working on my site, when I preview it in my browser though my IP address is showing up as '::1' every time. This is just using XAMPP as my testing server. Below is the code that inserts data, including user IP, into my database. Prior to this code I'm not collecting the users IP anywhere. Do IP addresses show up any different just previewing the site with a testing server vs. once the site is live? Or..does it look like I am missing something with my code? Thank you in advance.

```
$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

        Database::ExecuteQuery("INSERT INTO `rating` (`item_name`, `rating`, `ip_address`, `date_rated`) VALUES ('{$varItem}', '{$varRating}', '{$ipAddress}', NOW())", "InsertRating");
        Database::FetchResults("InsertRating");
        Database::FreeResults("InsertRating");
        Database::RemoveSavedResults("InsertRating");
```

Comment: ipv6 ip addresses ::1 is the same as ipv4 localhost or 127.0.0.1 or loopback.  Goto your network settings and turn off ipv6 for your interface

Comment: check with 'ip_address' data type to varchar with proper length